Why this two python lines return False?
"a" in ["a", "b"] is True
False is False in [True]

This two line return False. and, this return True.
"a" in ["a", "b"] == ["a", "b"]

Why? This is really confused.
I thought that's cause of order.
But... I don't know why that happening.

"chained comparisons" "a" in ["a", "b"] is True is treated as ("a" in ["a", "b"]) and (["a", "b"]) is True). which is True and False, which is False. Similarly for the other. To get what you probably intended, write ("a" in ["a", "b"]) is True

Look into this Comparisons
